# Can't parse JSON array of objects

Tags: java, node.js, json, gson

I have a NodeJS cloud function that takes a bunch of javascript objects (entries from a db) in the form of an array, and sends them to the client.

On the server I do this using:
`return JSON.stringify(result);`

Where "result" is the array of JS objects. Then I send data to the client.

In my Android client, I receive the String, and need to iterate through every object in the original array and process them separately. I can't! I always get errors like:

```
I: [Batch] com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1 column 3 path $[0].
```

On my Android client, I have tried:

```
WebItemEntry [] items = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, WebItemEntry[].class);
```

AND ...

```
ArrayList<WebItemEntry> items = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<WebItemEntry>>(){}.getType());
```

Neither seem to work. Same error as above.

The raw output I get from the database is the JSON string that consists of five individual entries that I would like to iterate through and parse. Its kind of a mess, but you can see its deliminator is the brace {. I really want to use GSON or similar in my android client to parse these entries individually and convert them to my custom Java class: WebItemEntry.

```
[{\"charityID\":0,\"purchaserZIP\":\"\",\"category\":\"Women\u0027s Accessories\",\"valueCents\":0}, {... same thing for a different entry here...}, {new entry ... }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server ignore `stringify` and return plain object, those `\"` characters appear when js object stringify twice. so replace `return JSON.stringify(result);` with `return result;`.

Comment: Bingo! That did it!